# Should I follow the naming conventions when I do MS SQL Server coding?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, naming-conventions

I am a junior web developer and currently reviewing existing SQL Server 2008 R2 database. I noticed that the existing database never followed the SQL Server convention standard such as database naming, table naming, column naming.

I asked the developer who developed the database about this, and he mentioned that he developed database code following the custom naming convention, not MS convention standard and as he still thinks that following the MS standard naming conventions is not mandatory but optional and should be flexible depending on a project.

As a junior developer, I don't want to have bad habits and wondering if his opinions are correct to follow.

Thank you for your opinions.

Comment: Of course, that will make life too easy in the future but that is all by choice.

Comment: One of the goals of naming standards to provide consistency. Maintenance will be easier if you continue to use the existing naming precedent, even if not to your liking. However, you could use a different standard when developing a new independent database.

Comment: it is up to you, but my view is if there is a naming convention that the company / development team is adopting, use that. It will be a nightmare if each developer adopt their own convention

Answer (score 1):

There is no single Microsoft SQL Server naming convention or standard. You will find that different conventions are in use in different places. What is important is that your code can be understood in the environment where you work. If your workplace has an accepted standard then that seems like the one to use.